# setting the right directory on css inject

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, gulp-inject

this is my project

```
 - Project root

 |-  build
     |-css
     |-js
     |-index.html

 |-  src
     |- css
     |- js
     |-index.html

 |-gulpfile.js
```

I use gulp and want to inject build/scc and build/js files  into src/index.html and place it as build/index.html

Done this :

```
gulp.task('index', function () {
  var target = gulp.src('src/index.html');
  var sources = gulp.src(['build/js/*.js', 'build/styles/*.css'], { ignorePath: 'build/', addRootSlash: false });
  return target.pipe(inject(sources))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

I need to skip the '/build/' part
But still on output of html file shows :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/styles/app.min.css">
<script src="/build/js/app.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: have you tried `"../build/xxx"`

Comment: nope,how you do that?

Comment: pretty simple just add `..` to jump up a folder like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../build/styles/app.min.css">`

Answer (score 0):

```
- Project root

 |-  build
     |-css
     |-js
     |-index.html

 |-  src
     |- css
     |- js
     |-index.html

 |-gulpfile.js
```

Now we are in `index.html` which is in `build` directory(folder), we need to go a step backward to have access to the `src` directory, and `..` will be the *parent directory of the current directory* (means `build`)

then you can use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../build/styles/app.min.css">
```

*Reading more about [relative and absolute path](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001708.htm) will help you to learn more about this*